# nspredicate using NSregularexpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I am using the following regular expression for matching a whole word in a string

```
(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])*test(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])* //ig
```

I have tested this regex on http://regex101.com/ and it works as expected using the below sample data.

Sample String:

```
these are words !@#$hello@#$$$ abc@123.com z,kakdk test test.sample@56789.com 8x11-1dc pages 123  123 TeSt test_2000
```

I need to use this regex to filter a array of string matching the regex using predicate. I am using the below code to do that but i am always getting zero output.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])*%@(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])*",searchTerm];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name MATCHES[c] %@",string];
```

Validated my regex with below code and it works fine:

```
NSString *someRegexp = @"(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])*test(?:[a-b][A-B][0-9])*";
NSString *testString = @"these are words !@#$hello@#$$$ abc@123.com z,kakdk test_2000 test.sample@56789.com 8x11-1dc pages 123  123 TeSt";
NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:someRegexp options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])];
```

Kindly help me out. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your post properly, making the code blocks readable.

Comment: I have added an answer below but in the event I misunderstood the question or you need to extract specific words/phrases from the string, please leave a comment and I'll gladly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a small solution that makes use of the `NSRegularExpression` class. In this particular instance, an `NSPredicate` is not required to match text in an arbitrary string.

The complete program in `main.m` is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *testString = @"these are words !@#$hello@#$$$ abc@123.com z,kakdk test_2000 test.sample@56789.com 8x11-1dc pages 123  123 TeSt";

        NSError *regexError = nil;
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\w+"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&regexError];

        if (regexError) {
            // handle error
            NSLog(@"%@", regexError.localizedDescription);
        }

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:testString
                                options:0
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, testString.length)
                             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                                 NSLog(@"%@", [testString substringWithRange:result.range]);

        }];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

First, we create the test string you've provided from the question as a local variable named `testString`.

Next, we have a local variable named `regexError` that will be used as an out parameter when creating the `NSRegularExpression` instance.

We then create an `NSRegularExpression` instance using a provided class method and pass in the address of `regexError` which will be set in the event of an error.

After creating the regular expression, we check to see if the error has been set and if so, handle it appropriately. Here we simply log a description of the error.

It is good to note that `\w` is a character class that matches letters, digits, and underscores. We need to escape it with a `\` since we are placing it in a literal `NSString` and the `+` sign indicates that we are interested in 1 or more, with the matches being large as possible.

Since the goal is to match words, we then enumerate the matches in the text string with a range that is equivalent to the string's length.

We are provided an `NSTextCheckingResult` as one of the arguments to the block and it has a property called `range` which we can use in conjunction with `NSString`'s `substringWithRange:` method to extract the matching word. Here we are simply logging the word.

Using your test string as an example, the output is as follows:

```
2014-08-06 13:39:56.195 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] these
2014-08-06 13:39:56.197 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] are
2014-08-06 13:39:56.198 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] words
2014-08-06 13:39:56.199 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] hello
2014-08-06 13:39:56.200 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] abc
2014-08-06 13:39:56.201 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 123
2014-08-06 13:39:56.201 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] com
2014-08-06 13:39:56.202 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] z
2014-08-06 13:39:56.203 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] kakdk
2014-08-06 13:39:56.203 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] test_2000
2014-08-06 13:39:56.204 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] test
2014-08-06 13:39:56.204 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] sample
2014-08-06 13:39:56.205 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 56789
2014-08-06 13:39:56.205 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] com
2014-08-06 13:39:56.206 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 8x11
2014-08-06 13:39:56.206 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 1dc
2014-08-06 13:39:56.207 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] pages
2014-08-06 13:39:56.207 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 123
2014-08-06 13:39:56.208 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] 123
2014-08-06 13:39:56.208 NSPredicate-NSRegularExpression[3914:303] TeSt
```